# Can I miss out the part on my secondary and high school education?

Tags: applications

A company I'm applying to has asked me to fill out my secondary and high school education on the application Word form they provided.

Unfortunately, I can't remember all the subjects I studied from 5 and 7 years ago, and I don't have transcripts or certificates to hand.

I have asked them if its OK if I just write my Bachelor/Master degree. If they insist, how do I go about getting transcripts or certificates?

Comment: Right, well done. As you've already asked them, what question do you want us to answer?

Comment: Usually you go with highest education and leave out highschool or middle school. I can't imagine there be any curriculum you'd need to list from that other than you graduated. However it's unclear what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Oh, they also asked for photocopies for the qualifications I have. But I don't even know where the secondary school/high school certificates are?...Oh, I am just worried how HR would respond?

Comment: This application/company is not in USA/Europe.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to keep education certificates permanently, just in case. Your family, or whoever you lived with at the time, may have your secondary and high school certificates.

Comment: I find it a bit hard to believe you don't remember what subjects you studied only 5 years ago - I can remember the grades I got at high school 21 years.

Comment: @HorusKol you are a superhuman (or your remembering false attributions as factual) ;)

Comment: @easymoden00b - remembering 10 subject grades from high school isn't hard  - admittedly, I had to use those grades on resumes 16 years ago, so it's a little fresher than 21 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Before, I get to my full answer, which will offer some suggestions as to how to get this info if you or your parents do not have any copy of your certificate/coursework, I have to ask - what is it the employer is looking for?  If it's proof of your graduation from Secondary/HighSchool, a copy of your transcript/diploma from your Bachelors/Masters program should suffice. If, for some reason, they're looking for a transcript, it's very likely your old school has a copy of that.

---

If you don't personally have a copy of your high school diploma, you can ask your school for a copy - they should have one on record.

Most employers are really only looking for whether or not you have graduated from secondary/highschool at all, so a full breakdown of your coursework probably isn't necessary - if they asked for it, again, this is something that you could ask for from the school itself.  They should have some type of electronic record of your certificate and/or transcript of your coursework.

If for some reason you cannot get the records from the school, and you have no way of finding it yourself, you could *also* consider asking your Bachelor/Masters school if *they* have a copy of said certificate/transcript on record - they should, if you applied for their school and got in/completed your coursework.

And if none of these sources have a copy of your certificate, then you can simply include a copy of your Bachelors/Masters, with an explanation on your cover letter/email that you attempted to contact your secondary/Highschool and Bachelors/Masters schools for a copy of your certificate/transcript, and that none of them had it on record - that you are therefore presenting a copy of your Bachelors/Masters certificate, as proof that you have completed your secondary/highschool degree.